# core data how to use the second entity

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data, entity

I have 2 entities the first one is a PERSON the second is an EVENT they have relation one-to-many.
my first tableView have names of PERSON (work well). now I want make another tableView with events of the selected person (selected by name from the first tableView).

I just want tableView with the names for example "Billy,Amanda". Billy have 2 events (birthday and shopping),
Amanda have 3 events (birthday,study,movie). when user press at Billy in the first tableView he get another tableView with: birthday and shopping..

how can I make it? 
it will be nice if someone write code examples or link me to tutorial.

Comment: It would be nice if you break the problem into small pieces and say which one(s) you don't understand.

Comment: @Phillip Mills I'm didn't sure how use core data to show in tableView events of specific person (that chosen by the user in the first viewTable).

Comment: Pass the person object to the second controller and that controller can use the relationship to find the events.  You don't need to use core data directly; you just use the object property.

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you for the help, so I just need use the property events (my relation name) without fetch and NSManageObjectContext..?

for example at my first tableView I use this method:
<br/>
<code>
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[[self fetchResultsController]sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects];
}
</code>
<br/>

can you give me example how write this method?
if my pass object named currentPerson.

Comment: Assuming you store it in a `currentPerson` property in your second controller: `return [self.currentPerson.events count];`.  The only complication is if you want the events to be displayed in a known order.  In that case, you might want to keep a `NSArray` property that has the event references in the order you want to show them.

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks as I thought, last question (I hope) if I want add new event to this exactly person, I just need create class of Event save the data in properties and after it use this Person's method - (void)addEventsObject:(Event *)value; and insert the Event object?

Comment: I **think** you've got it.  :)  Create it using the managed object context and the entity description, and then `addEventsObject:` to relate the objects.

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry but I don't understand how to use manage object context in this situation can you give me code example?

Comment: I understand:

- (void) addEventControllerDidSave:(NSString *)typeData{
    
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Event *newEvent = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newEvent setType:typeData];
    [currentPerson addEventsObject:newEvent];
    
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

thanks for the help :)